# How do I interpret the HW_BOOT_DATA field of nvram?

Tags: mac-mini, nvram

When I run `nvram -x HW_BOOT_DATA` the output in the `data` field appears to be a base64 encoded binary string. The length remains constant but some of the bits change between runs.

How do I interpret this field? What do the different bits mean?

I have a 2018 Mac Mini running macOS Monterey 12.6.